# Oracle BI: XSL-FO IE6 compatability issue with table cell row heights

Tags: oracle, internet-explorer-6, xsl-fo, html-table

We have an issue with the HTML produced from the Oracle BI publishing engine, in that the pages are not rendering properly in IE6. The issue is that of tables having their row heights hard coded, meaning that cells with multiple lines of text in them only display the first line, despite the fact that all data is present in the HTML source.

To clarify, all pages look fine when viewed in IE7 or above, and Firefox. The upgrade to IE8 is on its way (thank god), but not for another 6 months or so, so we need to find a temporary fix if possible.

Firstly, does anybody know if it is possible to enable some kind of IE6 compatibility mode on Oracle BI publisher through the Java APIS? (a long shot really I know).

Secondly, the transformation produced by the Oracle BI templates is an XLS-FO style sheet. Our plan B here is to manually edit this file to produce the desired output. I would assume it should be possible in here to try and set the heights of rows to be auto decided (or just not fixed), but so far to no avail, with the default "just one row" being displayed again.

Does anyone have any experience / advice with either Oracle BI and IE6, or tables in XSL-FO with cell heights expanding to match content in IE6?

Any help / advice is very appreciated!

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand this question. Web browsers such as IE display HTML. They do not know about XSL-FO. Why is XSL-FO involved here?

Comment: The XSL-FO is generated by processing RTF templates through Oracle BI. With this stylesheet and some XML data, the HTML is produced. Its in this HTML that the IE6 table row issue is occurring. As I said, we ideally need to change the XSL-FO so it produces HTML that looks good in IE6.

Comment: When you say XSL-FO, do you actually mean XSLT?

Comment: No, it is actual a combo of XSL and FO tags in there, and the documentation describes it as XSL-FO. We've found another way around this now anyways though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue it appears, was to downgrade the Oracle BI Publisher version that we were using. We are currently using version 11g, which according to documentation supports IE7 and 8, not IE6.

Version 10.134 on the other hand supports IE6 and 7. Downgrading the Java APIs to this version resulted in HTML that was IE6 compliant. Whilst in normal circumstances this would not be ideal, for our scenario 10.134 was already being used elsewhere in the business, and was proven to be stable in a live environment. In an ideal world, IE6 should have been updated, but unfortunately you can't win them all!